ROS2: ament_environment_hooks not sourcing .sh and .bash files
I'm using ROS2 Humble.
I have a package which at its top-level has .sh and .bash scripts I'd like sourced during colcon build to help setup my environment.
In ROS1, I've used syntax along the lines of this in my CMakeLists.txt:

catkin_add_env_hooks(setup_env SHELLS sh DIRECTORY
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/hooks)

In ROS2, I'm trying to use this within CMakeLists.txt (https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz_project_template/issues/16):

ament_environment_hooks("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/hooks/setup_env.sh.in")

After colcon build completes, I'm seeing setup_env.sh placed at ~/ros2_ws/install/<package_name>/share/<package_name>/environment/setup_env.sh as expected.
However, I'm not seeing it sourced when running source ~/ros2_ws/install/setup.sh after the build completes.
I do see it sourced just fine if I directly do a source ~/ros2_ws/install/<package_name>/share/<package_name>/environment/setup_env.sh (I have an echo statement in the script as an indicator).
I see this behavior for any script I want sourced (.zsh, .bash, etc.).
What gives? Am I interpreting the functionality correctly?

As it turns out, I was not making use of ament_cmake_python correctly in both my CMakeLists.txt and package.xml (I'm using both python and c++ in my package).
In my package.xml I had conflicting exports:
<export>
    <build_type>ament_python</build_type>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
</export>

removing ament_python line above and then having the following structure in my package.xml and CMakeLists.txt respectively, fixed the issue:
package.xml:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>package</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="example.com">user</maintainer>
  <license>Apache-2.0</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>
  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake_python</buildtool_depend>

  <depend>rclcpp</depend>
  <depend>rclpy</depend>

  <test_depend>ament_copyright</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_flake8</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_pep257</test_depend>
  <test_depend>python3-pytest</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>

CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project('project')

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# Find dependencies (this is important even for Python packages)
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
# uncomment the following section in order to fill in
# further dependencies manually.
# find_package(<dependency> REQUIRED)
find_package(ament_cmake_python REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(rclpy REQUIRED)

# Install Python modules
ament_python_install_package(${PROJECT_NAME})

# Register environment hooks (if any): https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz_project_template/issues/16
ament_environment_hooks("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/hooks/setup_env.sh.in")
ament_environment_hooks("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/hooks/setup_utils.bash.in")

# Check if we are on an Nvidia Xavier or Orin and install more hooks
if(EXISTS "/etc/nv_tegra_release")
  message(STATUS "Nvidia Xavier or Orin environment detected. Installing custom environment hooks.")

  ament_environment_hooks("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/hooks/setup_xavier_env.sh.in")
  ament_environment_hooks("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/hooks/setup_orin_env.sh.in")

else()
  message(STATUS "Non-Nvidia environment detected. Skipping Nvidia-specific environment hooks.")
endif()

# If you want to add tests, you can do so here (optional)
if(BUILD_TESTING)
    find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
    # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    # comment the line when a copyright and license is added to all source files                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    # comment the line when this package is in a git repo and when                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    # a copyright and license is added to all source files                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

# Required for ROS2 packages
ament_package()

